# What is the difference between #!/bin/bash and #!/usr/bin/env bash?

Tags: bash, scripts

In tutorials for Ubuntu scripting I see as first line of a script either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. What is the difference between those?